# Higher order functions is complex?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, higher-order-functions

I have read many articles, but there are still things I am having difficulty understanding. Where's the point I can't understand? My questions are in the code. I hope I asked right.

```
fun main() {
    /*
    1- Is it argument or parameter in numbers{} block?
    where is it sent to the argument? why do we send "4" if it is parameter?
    Are all the functions I will write in (eg println) sent to the numbers function? But this HOF can 
    only take one parameter.
    */
    numbers {
        /*
        2-How does this know that he will work 3 times?
        According to the following 3 functions? Is there a for loop logic??
        */
        println(it)
        "4" // 3- Which one does this represent? f:(String) or ->String?
    }
}

fun numbers(f: (String) -> String) {
    f("one")
    f("two")
    f("three")
    println(f(" - "))
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. There is no argument or parameter defined in your lambda block above. It's just the content of your lambda function. You've used the implicit single parameter name of `it`. `"4"` is the return value of your lambda.
2. The lambda itself isn't "aware" of how many times it will be called. In this case, it is called four times, because your numbers function invokes the parameter `f` four times.
3. A lambda's return value is whatever its last expression evaluates to. In this case, it returns the `String` `"4"`.

Maybe this will help. Lambda syntax is a convenience. But we can take away each piece of syntactic sugar one at a time to see what it actually means.

All of the code blocks below have the exact same meaning.

Here is your original statement:

```
numbers { 
    println(it)
    "4"
}
```

First, when a lambda omits the single parameter, it gets the implicit parameter name `it`. If we avoid using this sugar, it would look like this:

```
numbers { inputString ->
    println(inputString)
    "4"
}
```

The evaluated value of the last expression in a lambda is what it returns. You can also explicitly write a return statement, but you must specify that you are returning from the lambda, so you have to put its name. So if we put this in, it looks like this:

```
numbers { inputString ->
    println(inputString)
    return@numbers "4"
}
```

When a lambda is the last argument you pass to a function, you can put it outside the parentheses. This is called "trailing lambda". And if the function is the only argument, you don't need parentheses at all. If we skip this convenience, it looks like this:

```
numbers({ inputString ->
    println(inputString)
    return@numbers "4"
})
```

A lambda is just a very compact way of defining a function. If we define the function directly, it looks like this:

```
numbers(fun(inputString: String): String {
    println(inputString)
    return "4"
})
```

The function you are passing is the argument of the `numbers()` function. You can also define it separately and then pass the function reference like this:

```
fun myFunction(inputString: String): String {
    println(inputString)
    return "4"
}
numbers(::myFunction)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have some questions.

2- So where does return "4" go whenever a function is called? Actually return 4 is returned each time, but we can not see it because we did not print. Right?

About of the last code:
Is f = myfunction and parameter the "one" = (inputString: String). Right?

Comment: The `”4”` is what your function will return each time it’s invoked. In`numbers` you invoke it four times but you are ignoring the return value the first three times and only using it the fourth time when you print it. Sorry, I can’t understand what you’re asking in your last question.

Comment: "f()" in the numbers function represent to "myfunction()"?
So "one" parameter sended to myFunction(to here)?

Comment: Yes. Within the `numbers` function, you can call the function that's passed just like any other function. The parameter in the parentheses is the value you're passing for the parameter, just like when you call any function.

Comment: Thanks. I try some things: https://pl.kotl.in/JHSZsN57W
Why is the ignoring the 3 and 0 and does 3+3?

Comment: The content of your lambda function doesn't use `a` or `b`. It only outputs `3+3`. It's like writing any other function where you have parameters but don't use them. Like `fun ignoreMyParams(a: Int, b:Int): Int { return 5 }` If you wanted your function to return the sum of the two parameters, you could write it like `calculate(3,0,{a,b->a+b})`